# Как подключить JSON локально (с компьютера)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, require

Как можно к обычному js файлу, без использования фреймворков и локальных серверов подключить JSON файл ?

Answer (score 1):

Ну если максимально нативно, без всяких сборщиков и т.д., то мне пока только что-то вроде такого в голову пришло:

```
fetch('./youtJSON.json')
  .then(res=> res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не подходит, ругается консоль, пишет, что "URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."

Comment: Хм..я попробовал у себя на локалке развернуть такой код:

window.onload = function () {
    fetch('./test.json')
    .then(res=> res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
}

И у меня все сработало. Покажешь код сам?

Comment: На локалке в смысле на локальном сервере ?

Я скопировал код 1 в 1 как ты написал, только название json файла заменил

Comment: fetch можно только на локалке запустить если чисто в html то заблокирует, еще вроде как должно быть https. есть вариант подключить json в HTML <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script> и потом его обрабатывать

Comment: @Greg--, А как в таком случае можно его обработать ? Как обратиться к нему из js.файла ?

Comment: Это описано в стаковерфлоу английской версии там вместо json js пишут и задают как перменную, грубо говоря два js вариант [сомнительный](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24378510/14135825)

Comment: я пробовал и  jquery `$.getJSON` и fetch но хром блокирует с ошибкой `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

Comment: Лучший способ все же виртуальный сервер запустить или как в сомнительном примере загрузить в js и обрабатывать другим js